# Java regex to match mutiple substrings

Tags: java, regex

I am a noob in Java and i want a regex pattern to match sub strings in a sentence. I have multiple sub strings from which,

**i want to test if any of the sub string is there in my sentence or not**.

```
sub strings :  ice cream, coffee, new brand
```

Sentence1 : I have had ice cream this month.

Sentence2: I made the bill payment for coffee with card.

Sentence 3: He just signed with new brand this week

```
Regex for Substrings : "(ice cream|coffee|new brand).*"
```

What should be the correct regex in Java for this?

Comment: `"(ice cream|coffee|new brand)"` or `"\\b(?:ice cream|coffee|new brand)\\b"` will do with `Matcher#find`

Comment: Why you need regex for this ??

As per your question, your `String str = "ice cream, coffee, new brand";`

Why not split on the basis of **,**

    `String [] splitted = str.split(",");`

Comment: @VishwaRatna I will use this regex in wso2sp , as it is java based. I need to provide Java based regex

Comment: @RahulAnand , no worries friend, Wiktor has already gave you the regex in comment. Hope it helps.